# "might" vs "might have" in a narrative set in the past

Tags: past-tense

> The men kept walking well into the night, because if it rained the
>   next day, they might not [reach / have reached] the village before the
>   enemy arrived.  At around midnight, they came to a clearing a few
>   miles west of the village and finally decided to set up camp for the
>   night.

Which would you choose in this context, "reach" or "have reached"?

A colleague of mine insists that "have reached" is the only correct option because the sentence refers to a possibility in the past and that "might" can only refer to the present (e.g. "He might be a mathematician.")

In contrast, another colleague argues "reach" should be chosen because "have reached" is only reserved for situations where something happened before the point of reference (e.g. "The doctor suspected that the patient might have taken an overdose of the medication.")

I would tend to agree with the first ("reach") but I am not completely sure.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it doesn’t say, “because if it ***had*** rained the next day”...

Comment: @Jim That's the point I was trying to get at.  If the preceding clause is "if it _had_ rained the next day," "might have" would be the only choice.  Which would you choose in the context above?

Comment: I’d match tense with “if it rained” and choose “might not reach”

Answer (score 1):

I would personally not have written "might/might have" in that context, because it would sound a lot more natural if you changed it to

"Because if it rained the next day, they wouldn't reach the village before the enemy arrived."

Answer (score 1):

IMO “might not have reached” is the correct choice of the two, as it reflects the past tense in agreement with the context of the sentence.